# What about Hopf algebra and fusion structures for intertwiner algebras?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, hopf-algebras, symmetric-groups, fusion-categories, planar-algebras

Let $G$ be a complex, reductive group and let $V_1, \dotsc, V_r$ be a collection of finite dimensional, irreducible complex
representations of $G$. Let $\mathcal{A} = \mathrm{End}_G(V_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes V_r)$ be the algebra of $G$-invariant endomorphisms (*intertwiners*) of $V_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes V_r$.
Some popular examples include:

(1) the group algebra of the symmetric group  $\Bbb{C}\bigl[S_n\bigr] \cong
\operatorname{End}_{\operatorname{GL}(V)}\bigl(V^{\otimes n} \bigr)$
provided $\dim \, (V) \geq n$.

(2) the Temperley–Lieb algebra $\mathrm{TL}(n) \cong \operatorname{End}_{\operatorname{SL}(V)}\bigl(V^{\otimes n} \bigr)$ where $\dim \,(V)= 2$.

(3) the blob algebra $\mathrm{Blob}(n) \cong
\operatorname{End}_{\operatorname{SL}(V)}\bigl(V^{\otimes n} \otimes \mathrm{Sym}^n(V) \bigr)$ where $\dim \,(V)= 2$.

(4) the 5-th Okada algebra ${\mathfrak{F}}_5 \cong \operatorname{End}_{\operatorname{GL}(V)}\bigl(V^{\otimes 4} \otimes V^* \bigr)$
provided $\dim \, (V) \geq 5$.

Please feel free to add your favorite example to the list. Like any other group algebra $\Bbb{C}\bigl[ S_n \bigr]$ has the structure of a Hopf algebra. On the other hand, the Temperley–Lieb algebra $\operatorname{TL}(n)$ only has the structure of a *weak* Hopf algebra when $n$ is even (see section 2.7 of [Nikshych and Vainerman - Finite Quantum Groupoids and Their Applications](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0006057)). I have no idea whether the Blob algebra $\mathrm{Blob}(n)$ or the Okada algebra ${\mathfrak{F}}_5$ has a Hopf algebra structure - weak or otherwise. Nevertheless the Grothendieck group $G_0 \bigl( \operatorname{mod}\, {\mathfrak{F}}_5 \bigr)$ of the Okada algebra $\mathfrak{F}_5$ has a *fusion* product.

**Remark:** I should add that I'm not sure whether the weak Hopf algebra structure on $\operatorname{TL}(n)$ for $n$ even induces a fusion product
on the Grothendieck group
$G_0 \bigl({\operatorname{mod}}\text-{\operatorname{TL}(n)} \bigr)$. To be more precise: I am not aware of character table $X = (X^u_v)$ for $\operatorname{TL}(n)$ (one whose rows and columns are indexed by isomorphism classes of irreducible representations of $\operatorname{TL}(n)$
and whose rows are pairwise orthogonal)
such that

\begin{equation} 
\begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle K_{u,u'}^{u''} \, := \, \sum_{v \, \in \, \operatorname{Irr} \, \operatorname{TL}(n)} X^{u}_v \, X^{u'}_v X^{u''}_v z^{-1}(v) \\ \\
\displaystyle \text{where} 
\ z(v) \, := \, \sum_{w \, \in \, \operatorname{Irr} \, \operatorname{TL}(n)} X^w_v \, \overline{ X^w_v}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

is a non-negative integer for any triple $u,u',u''$ of $\operatorname{TL}(n)$ irreducible representations. Indeed, if there were, these
generalized "Kronecker" coefficients $K^{u''}_{u,u'}$ would be structure constants
for a fusion product, namely:

\begin{equation}
[u] * [u'] \, = \, 
\sum_{u'' \, \in \, \operatorname{Irr} \, \operatorname{TL}(n)} K^{u''}_{u,u'} \, [ u'' ].
\end{equation}

If anyone is aware of a character table
for $\operatorname{TL}(n)$ of this kind I would be happy to know; ditto for the blob algebra. In light of this remark, let me update the question.

**Updated Question:** Are there necessary and/or sufficient conditions for
$\mathcal{A} := \operatorname{End}_G(V_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes V_r)$
to be a Hopf algebra? When will its Grothendieck group $G_0(\operatorname{mod} \, \mathcal{A})$ have the structure of
a fusion ring?

thanks, ines.